# Set scope of closure to calling method

Tags: groovy

Is it possible to set the scope of Groovy closures to the calling method? See sample code below:

```
class TestClass {

  def testMethod() {
    def i = 42

    def closure = testClosure()
    closure.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST 
    closure.delegate = this.&testMethod
    closure() // Should print 42.
  }

  def testMethod2() {
    def i = 43

    def closure = testClosure()
    closure.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST 
    closure.delegate = this.&testMethod2
    closure() // Should print 43.
  }

  def testClosure = {
    println i // I get a MissingPropertyException: No such property i
  }
}

def test = new TestClass()
test.testMethod()
test.testMethod2()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can move `i` to the same scope as the closure:

```
class TestClass {

  def i

  def testMethod() {
    i = 42
    testClosure() // Should print 42.
  }

  def testMethod2() {
    i = 43
    testClosure() // Should print 43.
  }

  def testClosure = {
    println i // I get a MissingPropertyException: No such property i
  }
}

def test = new TestClass()
test.testMethod()
test.testMethod2()
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, I was afraid that might be the case. I have two Grails actions with 50% equal code and lots of common variables, and was hoping for an easy solution to unify both without passing all variables in a call to a common function (i.e. using a common closure instead that already has access to all the variables). But beside that it's not doable it's probably ugly as hell as well ;-)